# How to optimize the Glyphicons font?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, fonts, glyphicons

I want to optimize the loading of the Glyphicons font for the Google PageSpeed Insights tool. I need to apply the CSS code below :

```
font-display: swap
```

Here is the location of my font :

```
https://www.example.com/themes/custom/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old/bootstrap/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

I added the following code in the `style.scss` file of my sub-theme and I compiled the theme, but Google still says that I should apply `font-display: swap;`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../bootstrap/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-display: swap;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hard to say with the given info in the issue. The change looks alright. Is the new compiled CSS deployed to production environment?

Comment: @anderssonola Yes it is compiled and deployed in production, but the font is not taken into account. I have the impression that Bootstrap is being used in another file.